# Insert value on 0 index in dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a app dropdown.
`private appDropdownOptions: IDropdownOption[]`

I am assigning value to app dropdown from `appItems`.

```
this.appDropdownOptions = appItems.map(app => {
  return { key: app.appModuleIdUnique, text: app.name };
});
```

This is working fine , but i want to insert one default value on `index` 0.

```
{ key: this.appNoSelectionKey, text: 'Select' }
```

So how i can achieve it.

Comment: I have tried using the slice method but what i need to put on end like

Answer (score 1):

You can add one default value at `0` `index` and rest of `appItems` using spread operator like below:

```
this.appDropdownOptions = [{ key: this.appNoSelectionKey, text: 'Select' }, ...appItems.map(app =>  { key: app.appModuleIdUnique, text: app.name})]
```

Comment: Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'IDropdownOption' getting error

Comment: this.appDropdownOptions = [{ key: this.appNoSelectionKey, text: 'Select' }, ...appItems.map(app => {
      return { key: app.appModuleIdUnique, text: app.name };
    })];
this is working fine, do we need to specify return?

Comment: if you use curly braces `{}` then you will need to return but if you are using a one-line statement without curly braces you will not need to return it will automatically return. You can read more about arrow functions https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 0):

Try `unshift` method

```
this.appDropdownOptions = appItems.map(app => {
  return { key: app.appModuleIdUnique, text: app.name };
});

this.appDropdownOptions.unshift({ key: this.appNoSelectionKey, text: 'Select' });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.appDropdownOptions = appItems.map((app,index) => {
if(index===0){
return { key: this.appNoSelectionKey, text: 'Select' }
}
  return { key: app.appModuleIdUnique, text: app.name };
});
```